# socket.on event is repeating itself more than one time with every response

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets

I have set socket.emit event upon successful cooment. But the problem occurs when i bind sockets.on event. It is getting fired multiple times.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#comment_button', function() {
    $.ajax({
        // upon success
        success: function (response) {

            if (response) {
                socket.emit('postcomment');

                socket.on('refresh', function () {
                    console.log('refresh');
                  //This console.log('refresh') is coming multiple times. I mean its occurance increases with every successful ajax response.
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my server.js

```
socket.on('postcomment', function () {
        io.sockets.emit("refresh");
});
```

I have verified that in my server.js `socket.on` function is called for only one time.
I am not sure what is the problem with `socket.on('refresh', function () {}` in ajax.
Any help will be great.

> P.S socket connection is already made. No problem in that.
>
> EDIT: I rectified the mistake. If anyone is reading this in future.
>   As jason and Niranjan mentioned, `socket.on{}` event was binding themselves upon successful response. 
>   To be simple:
>   Every time the click handler is called, it attaches additional event listeners to the socket. The listeners you attached on the previous clicks remain active.

so i made the following changes wrt to previous code

```
 $(document).on('click', '#comment_button', function() {
    $.ajax({
        // upon success
        success: function (response) {

            if (response) {
                socket.emit('postcomment');

        }
    });
});

socket.on('refresh', function () {
    console.log('refresh');
});
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Are you binding multiple copies of the function to the `socket.on` `refresh` event?

Comment: when are you calling the ajax function??

Comment: No only console.log('refresh');

Comment: Upon successful comment. i am getting response for only one time when a user comments on a pic or video. @Niranjan

Comment: are you sure ajax is not getting call multiple times??

Comment: pretty sure @Niranjan I have checked and rechecked ajax response. So i am pretty sure

Comment: Not response bro, if u call ajax 20 times, your socket will repeat 20 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92382/discussion-between-sagar-patro-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Comment: I mean I think that's what's happening... it binds a new copy of the anonymous function every time the `ajax` call succeeds.

Comment: It might be. thanks Niranjan and jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i made the following changes wrt to previous code.
It Worked.

```
$(document).on('click', '#comment_button', function() {
    $.ajax({
        // upon success
        success: function (response) {

            if (response) {
                socket.emit('postcomment');

        }
    });
});

socket.on('refresh', function () {
    console.log('refresh');
});
```

> socket.on{} event was binding themselves upon successful response. To
>   be simple: Every time the click handler is called, it attaches
>   additional event listeners to the socket. The listeners you attached
>   on the previous clicks remain active.

Answer (score 2):

What i feel is, sockets are working fine. May be, `ajax()` is getting called multiple times.

For example, you are calling `ajax()` on click of something. and on success `socket.on('refresh')` gets executed. So now, if the user is clicking multiple times on button, ajax will be called that many times. This leads to repetation on `sockets()`

So make sure that, you dont call the ajax multiple times.

Your issue is solved:)

Answer (score 1):

You're attaching another copy of the anonymous function inside of the `socket.on` `refresh` function every time an `ajax` request succeeds.

I made this test. If I click the ajax button and then click the "click me" button, I get one "howdy" in the console. If I click the ajax button again then click "click me", I get "howdy" twice. Click ajax again, "click me" prints "howdy" three times, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

function send_ajax_request() {
    $.ajax("http://localhost/test.html").done(function() {
        console.log("ajax done");
        $("#clicker").click(function() {
            console.log("howdy");
        });
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="ajax request" onclick="send_ajax_request()">
<input type="button" value="click me" id="clicker">
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
So the solution, if your goal is simply to set up some behavior for the `socket.on` `refresh` event, is to assign that behavior outside of the `ajax` function and outside of any function that may be called multiple times.

Comment: So how would i avoid attaching another copy of anonymous function inside of the socket.on refresh function so that i wont get howdy multiple times? @jason